# JPA is not persisting child entities created with static methods

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, cascade

I frequently have to create a record that has child records.  I created a utility class U that is not managed by the container with a static method to create the objects.  It creates the required entities and relates them to each other and then returns the parent entity - BUT DOES NOT PERSIST.

When I go to persist the parent entity I expect all the attached child entities to be persisted as well but only the parent is persisted.

In another place, quite by accident, I noticed that if I created and attached the entities to the parent in class X that is not directly managed by the container but was created by a class C that was managed by the container - everything works as expected.  One other thing to note is that in this case the parent already existed so I set the ID on the child when I created it.

Does this mean I cannot create entities using static methods?  Or is there something else going on?

Here are the entities in question.

PARENT:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "INFO_ID_GEN", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "INFO_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "INFO_ID",allocationSize=1)
@Column(name="INFO_ID")
private int infoId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="PARENT", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private CHILD child;
```

CHILD:

```
@Id
@Column(name="INFO_ID", insertable=false)
private int infoId;

@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="INFO_ID")
private PARENT parent;
```

If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: Please add code of each class from the up, add also the utility class U

Comment: I have to be careful with what I post as I deal with very sensitive information.  I will try to get a "safe" version posted ASAP.